# Git OSX Push Files not showing up

Tags: git, macos

I just started using git on my Mac a few days ago, and I have some issues when I try to push files in a repository.

Everything seems to work fine when I execute the commands:

- `git add --all`
- `git commit -am test`
- `git push origin master`

But when I ask to a friend to pull the files on his own computer, the folder appears, but is empty. I know it's not a permission issue because my friend shouldn't be able to see the folder if it was a permission issue.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: What happens if you try to fetch the files?  Have you considered creating a new clone of the repository in a new directory somewhere and see what you see then?  Can your friend push stuff to the origin and can you see what he pushes?

Comment: After every git cmd, it's better to have a check if the cmd executes successfully and what the status is afterwards. Before and after `git add`, we can run `git status` to see which files have been modified and if the right files have been added. After `git commit`, we could use `git log -1` to see if the latest commit is what we expect. During `git push`, the output tells if everything is okay or something wrong happens. Besides, we could run `git fetch origin master && git log FETCH_HEAD -1` to see if the remote git repo has been updated as we expect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We did this, but still he can't see the files, only the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay just tried what you said, and apparently everything worked fine, but the files still are invisible for another user than me.

Comment: @IsmaëlDabo Can your friend see anything related to the master branch by `git branch -a`? Did your friend try `git checkout master`, though Git is expected to check it out by default?